# JavaFX TableView - is there a simple "classic" way to work with it?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

All the examples I've found over the web, about manipulating the data inside a TableView widget of JavaFX, were using an API that was not ever common for Table widgets in GUI libraries (Model class, Observable lists and such...).

Is there a simple way to use this table widget, i.e. without a model class?

I would be very glad if there were simple methods, like:

```
table.getModel().setValue(rowIndex, colIndex, someData);
table.addEmptyRow(index);
```

Is there anything like this in JavaFX?

Comment: Maybe a [GridPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) is the appropriate control for you rather than a TableView.

Comment: But GridPane is a layout... I want a table widget, that has columns with headers and that can be sorted, edited, etc.... In GUI libraries like Swing, Qt, Tk and others, the API is much simpler, like I wrote above

Comment: I think what I'll finally do is to create another class that will `extend` the TableView, with the API I like to have and I'll post it here

Answer (score 1):

You can always just make a `TableView<Object[]>`. Then

```
table.getModel().setValue(rowIndex, colIndex, someData);
table.addEmptyRow(index);
```

just become

```
table.getItems().get(rowIndex)[colIndex] = someData ;
table.getItems().add(new Object[numColumns]);
```

respectively. (Or similar code for a `TableView<List<Object>>`, if you prefer.)

Just more as a comment: I think in almost all cases (whatever toolkit you use), having a model class for the table rows makes things simpler than the old Swing style, which the above code emulates. The problem with this style is that your code loses all the semantics of what you're actually displaying. The only exceptions might be something like a general database (or CSV/tab-delimited file) viewer.

**Update**

This approach will only work if the data are not going to change while the table is displayed, and if you set all the data before you display it. This is because the `TableView` uses JavaFX observable properties to get notifications of changes to the data.

You could sort of modify it as follows:

```
    TableView<List<ObjectProperty<Object>>> table = new TableView<>();
```

Then adding a new row becomes

```
table.getItems().add(IntStream.range(0, numCols)
    .mapToObj(colIndex -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and setting a value becomes

```
table.getItems().get(rowNumber).get(columnNumber).set(someValue);
```

At this point, it almost certainly becomes easier to use the API the way it was intended, and create a model class for the row items.

Comment: I tried this solution, but for some reason, the updates I make are not shown in the table. Should I do any "commit"?